# Accessing data that was saved with jquery .data()

Tags: jquery, iframe

I have a iframe and I used the jquery `.data()` function to save some element from the iframe.
I attached them to the body like this `$('body').data('clicksData', myClicksData);`
Now i need to access that information from out of the iframe, I tried just doing this `var allData = $('body').data('clicksData')[0];` but it didnt work.
any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :

assign some id to your iframe like this :

```
<iframe id="frameId"></iframe>
```

and use this jquery code to access that iframe

```
$("#frameId").contents().find("body").data("clicksData");
```

Comment: Thank you, but that didnt help it tells me that the hole thing in undefined, does the iframe have his own body tag?

Comment: why its not working dude......you added id to iframe and use my code to access the that iframe body..

Comment: It doesnt recognize my object that i added to the body with the .data() function, and i know it is fersure there, he finds the body but not my data.

Comment: then try setting data using $("#frameId").contents().find("body").data('clicksData',myClicksData); and access that body it will surely work

Comment: I did that and didnt work :( from in side the iframe i can access the data perfectly fine, but from out side it doesnt work. any other good ideas?

Comment: then use cookies...which you can access it from anywhere in page

Comment: didnt get it what should i do?

Comment: look at the answer i have given and see the tick option...and accept it by clicking on tick button